# Find the unknown vector

Tags: vector-spaces

I have some vector related question. Think there are two vector $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ and angle between two vectors is $\theta$.It is also given. Vector $\vec a$ was given in $\vec i$ and $\vec j$ format and vector $\vec b$ only magnitude was given. The question is what are the components of vector $\vec b$ and write in $\vec i$ and $\vec j$ format.

Can someone explain what is the theory behind that. It’ll very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $$\vec a= a_1\vec i + a_2\vec j$$
and $$\vec b = x\vec i + y\vec j$$
You're given the angle between these two and the magnitude of $b$ vector.
Hence using dot product we must have
$$\frac{\vec a\cdot\vec b}{|a||b|}=\cos (\theta )$$
That implies
$$\cos \theta = \frac{a_1x+a_2y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cdot \sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}} $$
Let $|\vec a|=\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}=k$ hence we have
$$\underbrace{\cos^2 (\theta ) \cdot k^2}_{ \text{ constant}=A}\cdot (x^2+y^2)= (a_1x+a_2y)^2$$
Hence you have
$$(A-a_1^2)x^2-2a_1a_2xy+(A-a_2^2)y^2=0$$
Hence from here you can continue by dividing both sides by $y^2$ making it a quadratic in $t=\frac{x}{y}$. Solving you'll get corresponding values. And this will definitely resolve your problem.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. Can you please explain the bottom part of the answer. I can’t quite get it. Because I’m some kind of new to this type of question.

Comment: Ok . So dividing by $y^2$ both sides we get the equation $$(A-a_1^2)t^2-2a_1a_2t+(A-a_2^2)=0$$ where $t=x/y$. Now you've to solve this quadratic which will give u two values for $t$ let's denote it with $t=z_1,z_2$ then we have $x=z_1y, z_2y$. Now verify this through the given equation that is the modulus of the$\vec b$. I hope it's clear now and is appropriate for an upvote ;).